# C Scanf input testing for expected input format

Tags: c, testing, input, scanf

I need to make a simple C program which will solve quadratic equation in expected format that needs to be like this:

> a x^2 + b x + c = d x^2 + e x + f

I'm using scanf to read the input, and it works as expected. But I need to implement some input testing for my scanf reading which is like that right now:

```
scanf("%f x^2 + %f x + %f = %f x^2 + %f x + %f", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
```

I need to `printf("Wrong input\n");` for every input like f.e.

*'abc', '1 x^2 + 1 x + 1 = 0', 'x^3...'*

I tried the `if (scanf() != 1)`, but it prints the 'Wrong output' every time.
Any ideas about how can I accomplish that?

Comment: try `if (scanf(....) != 6)`.

Comment: It works, but how can I accomplish the 'Wrong input' when the input is not complete? F.e. if I enter only '1 x^2 + 1 x + 1 = 0' it waits for next possible input...

Comment: You will probably have to start reading user input as a string of characters and parse it yourself.

Comment: @JiříPašek Check my answer it tells you how to handle your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I enter only '1 x^2 + 1 x + 1 = 0' it waits for next possible
>   input.

In that case read complete input using `fgets` and parse the values using `sscanf` as below.

```
  char buf[100];
  fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin);

  int r = sscanf(buf,"%f x^2 + %f x + %f = %f x^2 + %f x + %f", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
  if (r!=6)
     printf("Wrong input\n");
  else
     printf("correct\n");
```